# CSS selector (or JavaScript if needed) for select DIV's which contain at least one UL

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Suppose I have a hierarchy like this:

```
<div class="first_level">
  <div class="second_level_1">
    <div class="third_level_1">
      <div class="fourth_level_1">
        <ul><li></li><li></li></ul>
      </div>
      <div class="fourth_level_2">
        <div class="fifth_level_1">
        </div>
        <div class="fifth_level_2">
          <ul><li></li><li></li></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second_level_2">
    <ul><li></li><li></li></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select all those divs, which contain at least one `ul` in them. So in the above example code, that would be divs `second_level_2`, `fourth_level_1` and `fifth_level_2` ..

What CSS selector can I use to get this result ?

**EDIT:**

If it's not possible with CSS alone, you can suggest answers using JavaScript, although due to the nature of my actual code, I would **really** like to avoid that if possible ..

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xWcbW)

Comment: You can't, not with CSS. You'd need to use JavaScript; css has no ability to select a parent element based on its children ([Not even in CSS 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#overview), with reference to the subject-selector, before someone posts that).

Comment: @DavidThomas Looks like CSS4 has a selector for this `E! > F`

Comment: I know that in CSS you cannot select parents based on child elements, but you can go from parent > child .. So can't this link be used somehow ?

Comment: @ced-b: seriously? Did you *read* the link I posted..? Yes, it *exists*, but it's *not* usable in the 'Fast Selector profile,' which is the one used in browsers. I guess I linked to the wrong section somehow, read this part: [Fast vs Complete Selector profiles](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#profiles). Ahmad: how do you propose to style the parent of an element by selecting its children? What exactly do you want to *do* with them?

Comment: @ced-b I know it is a lot to take in, but to summarize the *fast* selector profile must be implemented by CSS4 compliant user-agents.  It excludes the subject indicator

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Ahmad: please, what do you want to *do* to the elements you're selecting? If it's styling them then there might be alternative means to achieve your aim by styling the children. If it's something else, then we'd need to know so we can help.

Comment: I have modified my post to allow for JS based answers, although I'd really like to avoid that if possible ... I have a navigation menu which has a lot of entries coming in `ul li` .. These `ul` are contained within certain `divs` .. I want to target those `divs` through CSS, so I can apply CSS to them to style the containing `ul`s .. because the lists are generated dynamically, they don't have any `id` or `class` which I could have used to target them .. So my only alternative it to 'find' them using CSS ..

Comment: And 'style [them]' *how*?

Comment: The `ul`s contain lots of `li`s vertically. I want to break the list so that the `ul` distributes the list over multiple columns, as done here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bChDq .. Note that I'm using a `container` div here. I can't use this in my actual code because like I said, I don't have access to id or classes there ..

Comment: The code in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bChDq is for chrome only right now ..

Comment: I am using jQuery elsewhere on my site, so yes I can re-use jQuery here if needed ..

Comment: not possible with pure css, you have to use jquery

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry if I said something wrong, but I was thinking, if we are talking CSS4, we are talking about a bright new future, not necessarily something that can be implemented right now. Anyways, to say something constructive I left an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: _“I want to target those divs through CSS, so I can apply CSS to them to style the containing uls”_ – if you want to style those UL directly, then why would you have to target the DIVs first? (And why are those DIVs there anyway, if they contain _only(?)_ the UL …?)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options - both have downsides, but you can consider them:

You can either manually add a second class to the divs with a `ul`:

```
<div class="fourth_level_1 div_with_ul_class">
```

Note: If you are using some dynamic language on the server, such as PHP, this could actually be implemented fairly easily, without manual coding.

Or if you want to be dynamic I recommend jQuery:

```
$("div > ul").parent().addClass("div_with_ul_class");
```

Answer (score 1):

Parent selector isn't available in CSS, despite a lot of requests to add it.

jQuery has a nice selector, know as `:has`; http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

```
$('div:has(ul)');
```

Would be the jQuery selector.