# Break UL into multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It is difficult to extract code and post it here, so I'm posting a sample site which demonstrates my problem. I've been thinking about this, and there are several ways to solve this problem (HTML modification, CSS + HTML modification, CSS + JS modification), but since I'm a n00b at web coding, I want to know what is the best plan of attack here.

Anyways, the problem:

**Have a look here:** http://321cart.com/sellya/

Open the **Categories** Navigation menu, and you get this:

[image]

All those links under the categories are `ul` containing lots of `li`. I want to break the list and spread the list of multiple columns, *so that there are only a maximum of 3 `li` in one column*. Here is an example of what I want to do:

[image]

This is the overall thing that I want:

[image]

This will cause the menu width to increase (virtually double, in theory), but that is okay for me. I can deal with this on my own.

There are several methods to do this, but I would prefer if there's some way to do this using only CSS modification. If not, then maybe through CSS and JavaScript modification ? I want to reserve changes to actual HTML code as a last resort, because that is the original PHP HTML generation OpenCart code which I don't want to modify.

Please note that I did try to resolve this problem on my own, but it proved to be a little complex .. So don't think I didn't try .. Secondly, posting this in a JSFiddle would have been difficult to, and it would not have truly represented the actual problem fully, which is why I'm posting a link to a sample site.

Please have a look guys. Site: http://321cart.com/sellya/

So I need some answers for this problem that has me baffled.

**EDIT:**

Forgot to point this out. In the example I provided, all `ul`s had more than 3 `li`s each, but in my actual case, only a few `ul`s have more than 3 `li`s each, and I **only** want to extend those ones to 2 columns, not the ones will 1, 2 or 3 `li`s each.

Comment: You've put so much effort on this question, I was expecting a fiddle.

Comment: I would have loved to do that, you can you understand that taking this code out, along with its CSS, would have been a major task in itself. Yes, I could have made some smaller model example and posted that, but then people start to suggest answers applicable only to that small model code and not the actual problem. I didn't want that to happen, which is why I posted the URL to an actual sample site showing the problem.

Comment: Follow-up to [CSS selector (or JavaScript if needed) for select DIV's which contain at least one UL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947591/css-selector-or-javascript-if-needed-for-select-divs-which-contain-at-least-o) – why are you asking a second question about basically the same problem right after the first one?

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 introduced columns, which should do what you want. In theory, simply apply a height and `column-width` to your `ul`. In practice, you might need to use vendor prefixes on the `column-width`, giving you `-webkit-column-width`, `-moz-column-width`, etc. [Try it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/ty6vX/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the outer divs width (the ones with "span2" class in the provided link) to something like 350px and set LIs width to 100px and float:left directive. This is the simplest approach you can use.

Comment: I need a more clever solution than that. In the example I provided, all `ul`s had more than 3 `li`s each, but in my actual case, only a few `ul`s have more than 3 `li`s, and I only want to extend those ones to 2 columns, not the ones will 1, 2 or 3 `li`s each.

Comment: In this case you can easily check the number of LIs on each UL using JS and add a CSS class to those with more than 3 LIs that uses the float approach. Of course this is one alternative.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

```
var $columns = $("#columns");
var $longlist = $("#longlist");
var columnscount = 3;

//calculate sigle column size
var columnsize = Math.ceil($("p", $longlist).size() / columnscount);

//iterate number of columns, take [columnsize] elements, move them to div#columns and wrap with div.column
for (var i = 0; i < columnscount; i++) {
    $("p:lt(" + columnsize + ")", $longlist).appendTo($columns).wrapAll("<div class='column'/>")
}
```

you would need to add some condition to avoid spliting list shorter that 3 elements.

and this is how it works:
 http://jsfiddle.net/hGWjd/